# Correct way of making Uri for content resolver?

Tags: android

Reading previous posts, I can check all the content provider there are on my system.

I was wondering what is the correct way of making Uri's for the content resolver? Do we just put the whole path like `Uri.parse("content://org.company.example.sampleprovider/items");` or should we go step by step like

```
 Uri.builder.scheme("content://"); 
 Uri.builder.authority("org.company.example.sampleprovider");
```

What is the correct next step to get the items? How is the Uri.matcher used? in this whole procedure?